# Jmeter: How do I create a separate report for each assertion?

Tags: http, jmeter, assertion, jmeter-5.0

Right now, my HTTP call has 3 assertions. The reporting options for the results listener only provide a checkbox for "Assertion Results", which lumps all of my assertion results into one value in the CSV output.

The team would like to create a csv output for each assertion. The problem is, you can't add a results listener under an assertion, it must be under the HTTP call. I can't think of a way to create separate reports besides making three separate HTTP calls, each with their own results listener writing a report. That is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with jtl with XML.

Below is the config. Use minimum parameter required as it consume a lot of resource.
[image]
Below is the output.
[image]

But i think if you try to have response time in the same then there will be same entry twice. Similarly, other calculation might get impacted. So, you can use two one this and other simple data writer.

Hope this helps.